# How to hide parts of a object without boolean?

Tags: texturing, modifiers

Doing a concept of a feature for a game and need to make the map only appear in a little zone, but it should move and everytime it moves or a change something the boolean cut half of my processor and sometimes it dont work properly.

I Thinked about weight and dynamic paint but i know just the basics of it and couldnt get any results[image][image][image]